# WPF RichTextBox with variable number of TextBlocks (created using ItemsControl) loses selection behavior

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml

I need to show some content in a multi-line textbox in wpf, and some of that content, I want to show bold (or any such formatting I want to do).

So I ended up searching for a control and found that RichTextBox would do the job by using Run control inside that. Something like this:

```
    <RichTextBox>
        <FlowDocument>
            <Paragraph>
                <Run Text="Text to be displayed in Bold" FontWeight="Bold"/>
                <Run Text="Normal text"/>
            </Paragraph>
        </FlowDocument>
    </RichTextBox>
```

So this is nice, I can select content in this, and it has got nice formatting also.

But now the next problem is, that this content is dynamic, which I would create in the viewModel. So I tried to use ItemsControl Inside RichTextBox as shown below:

```
    <RichTextBox>
        <FlowDocument>
            <Paragraph>
                <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding MyCollections}">
                    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <!--< I want to use Run here, so that the content inside textbox is selectable, and I can even do formatting on Run >-->
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding MyTextInCollection}" />
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                </ItemsControl>
            </Paragraph>
        </FlowDocument>
    </RichTextBox>
```

But I can't use Run inside the DataTemplate (as shown in code as commented), so I tried using TextBlock.

Now the problem is, the basic selection behavior which TextBox should have, that is gone now. I want to do selection (by using Ctrl A, or clicking and dragging mouse) and want to do copy of text as well. Which I can't do now.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: you don´t use runs, because...? It doesn´t work? The title is kind of misleading since your text is based on textblocks instead of runs.

Comment: Ok, I will just edit the question to be more clear. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it working by this way:

Took a RichTextBox in the xaml giving it a name

```
<RichTextBox x:Name="MyTextBox" IsReadOnly="True" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" Margin="5" />
```

And then in code-behind, I create document with paragraph and Run's and bind it to the RichTextBox like this:

```
FlowDocument fd = new FlowDocument();
        fd.LineHeight = 1;
        foreach (var item in ((MyViewModel)this.DataContext).MyCollections)
        {
            Paragraph p = new Paragraph(new Run(item.MyTextInCollection) { FontWeight = FontWeights.Bold }); // bold text 
            Paragraph p = new Paragraph(new Run(item.MyTextInCollection)); // text with no formatting
            fd.Blocks.Add(p);
        }
        MyTextBox.Document = fd;
```

This way I have got the formatting of the content, as well as the selection behaviour which I need is intact.

I know I am doing that in code-behind and not in xaml, but that is fine, because this is purely view content which I did in the code-behind and nothing of business logic which should be there in ViewModel

Answer (score -1):

Here in  tag onClick event is not given in such cases prefer Javascript

IJavaScriptExecutor jspop = (IJavaScriptExecutor)driver;

IWebElement elementpop = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("html/body/div/ul/div"));

jspop.ExecuteScript("arguments[0].click()", elementpop);

Comment: Madhu, it's about a WPF control. I have just edited the heading of the question to be more clear.

Comment: WPF not javascript ;)